# Is it possible to model a lens with fixed focal length?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am trying to simulate a hexagonal shaped [plano-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plano-convex_lens) lens with a fixed focal length of 3mm. Is there any way to simulate lens with fixed focal length in blender?

Length of the longest diameter of the lens is considered as 1.5mm and glass BDSF as the material to the lens with 1.5 IOR.

Comment: It might be. What is the context? Just a model? A render? How does it have to look, what does it have to do, what's the purpose? Even with recent significant improvements Cycles is not perfect for simulating refractive caustics (light going through lenses and hitting other objects), but it will show what one would see through a lens just fine.

Comment: I am trying simulated a lenslet array which will be used in a light field camera. It is not just a model. It needs all optical character of lens. So refractive caustics is not accurate in cycles?

Comment: Absolute terms like "accurate" do not apply to any rendering process or even computer simulations. You could say "accurate enough". Cycles is very slow with Caustics. [LuxCoreRender](https://luxcorerender.org/), Octane or Maxwell or Thea render engines would probably be better for this. LuxCoreRender is probably best integrated to Blender and is open source and free so that's probably what you want to try.

Comment: In LuxCoreRender, Is it possible to simulate lens with fixed focal length?

Comment: An "accurate simulation" is an oxymoron, no? :) Do you want to do is set up a camera in Blender, that works like an orthographic camera on one axis, and like a perspective camera on another? Otherwise not sure what kind of an image would be produced by a lens like that - just a 2D image in a way? With one axis blurred?

Comment: It's not clear what the goal is. "simulated lenslet array which will be used in a light field camera" doesn't say much. How do you want to simulate it? Why? What's the context? What result are you after? What's it's purpose? Do you want to render an image as if it was taken by the camera or do you want to somehow visualise how that camera looks or works, or do you want to get insight how some geometry of the lens would actually work or something like that?..

Comment: I want to render the image as it was taken by the light field camera. The main difference of this camera from a normal camera is the placement of the lenslet array. The most basic element of a lenslet array is a hexagonal shaped plano-convex lens. So I'm trying to simulate a single hexagonally shaped plano-convex lens. The only constraint is that I need a lens with a fixed focal length.

Comment: That you can do. You need dense geometry so the curvature is represented well, but if you look through the lens, it will calculate refraction.  Cycles will ignore dispersion and some other effects, but that can work. See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126669/60759